# The latest (version: Fishtown.SR2) spring-cloud-stream doesn't support kafka client version 2.1.0 or higher?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am using latest Greenwich.SR1 which include spring-cloud-stream (version: Fishtown.SR2) and locally starting kafka client version:2.2.0 using kafka_2.12-2.2.0.jar

I want to use the latest kafka client 2.1 or higher with spring-cloud-stream because it contains some important bug fixes. But when I run my spring app, its logs says

```
INFO 37812 --- [main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser : Kafka version : 2.0.1
```

How can I use spring-cloud-stream with the latest kafka client?
I want to use **max.task.idle.ms** from the latest [StreamsConfig](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/index.html) of kafka client but it seems the latest spring-cloud-stream kafka stream binder doesn't [support](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/wiki/Kafka-Client-Compatibility) kafka client 2.1.0 or higher version?

Answer (score 0):

Spring versioning rules don't allow us to upgrade to a new version of the kafka clients in a point release. Since Fishtown uses Spring for Apache Kafka 2.2, it uses the 2.0.x kafka-clients.

The next version of Spring for Apache Kafka will use the 2.2.0 clients (or 2.3.0 if it's available by then), so the next version of the binder will be based on the newer clients.

The message channel binder works when the kafka-clients is overridden but, unfortunately, the streams binder does not due to some internal API changes.

Comment: YMMV, but I just tested a simple app with the kafka-clients and kafka-streams jars overridden to 2.2.0 and had no problems.

Comment: I have overridden the kafka-clients by adding a kafka-clients dependency version 2.2.0 and kafka-streams version 2.2.0 in my spring-cloud-stream pop.xml file. On app startup now I can see: [main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser : Kafka version: 2.2.0. Is this the correct way to override kafka-clients & kafka-streams  dependency? Does it mean that now I can use all the new features provided by kafka-clients & kafka-streams 2.2.0 in my spring-cloud-stream app. Thanks

Comment: Yes; as long as the broker version supports the feature.